# Resource False Error Reported by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building a Xamarin app and there's a really irritating Visual Studio fail which I would like to try and get rid of.

First up, the app builds fine. It deploys without a problem.
However, in every `Fragment` file, the `Resource` class is underlined in red and if I hover over it, it reads:

> "The name Resource does not exist in the current context".

I'm talking about the generated class which holds all the stuff you put in xml files, like `Resource.Id.NameOfTextView`

Any ideas how I can resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons Xamarin can get confused like this. I think its just an intelisense bug

if cleaning removing `bin` and `obj` directories and restart doesn't help, you will have to try a plethora of other things.

- Trying unloading and reloading the project so the resources are rebuilt.
- Make sure your nugets are up to date. i know this is weird but sometimes reinstalling all the packages helps
- Check namespace in Resource/Resource.Designer.cs and set [Specify Default Namespace](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/specify_default_namespace/) it can happens when your activity namespace is not in the same name space as your Resource.Designer.cs
- If you are using resharper try suspending it and unsuspending it, in the case its causing the issue

Comment: I've tried all of those except the Nuget suggestion. That'll take a bit of time, but is worth a try.

Comment: I ran the command and it worked. I confess I was skeptical. But was pleasantly surprised. So I doff my cap to you sir. Thanks!